# Kivy : How do you set a widget height relative to its parent 's height from the .py code?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Is it possible to set a Widget's height relative to the parent height in Kivi?

For example: let's say I want to place a rectangle and then place three lines inside, each equal to 1/3 of the height of the rectangle so that the three lines piled up fills the rectangle :

I would go with this approach

**Python File**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,ObjectProperty

class MyLine(Widget):
    y = NumericProperty(0)

class MyRectangle(Widget):
    line0 = ObjectProperty(0)
    line1 = ObjectProperty(0)
    line2 = ObjectProperty(0)
    def placeLines(self):
        self.line0.y = 0
        self.line1.y = self.height * 1/3
        self.line2.y = self.height * 2/3

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        myRectangle = MyRectangle()
        myRectangle.placeLines()
        return myRectangle

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**.KV File**

```
#:kivy 1.1.1

<MyLine>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:1,0,0,1
        RoundedRectangle:
            radius:[5.0,]
            pos: self.x, self.y
            size:self.width,self.height

<MyRectangle>:
    size:root.width, root.height
    line0 : MyLine0
    line1:MyLine1
    line2:MyLine2
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:0,0,1,1
        Line:
            width:2
            rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)
    
    MyLine:
        id:MyLine0
        size:self.parent.width, self.parent.height/3
    MyLine:
        id:MyLine1
        size:self.parent.width, self.parent.height/3
    MyLine:
        id:MyLine2
        size:self.parent.width, self.parent.height/3`
```

Only this result in the lines being stacked together at the bottom of the rectangle.

How can I set the Y position of the height so that thy're equal to 0, 1/3 and 2/3 of the **current** size of the rectangle?

Screenshot of the current result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `placeLines()` inside the `build()` method, the `height` of `MyRectangle` has not yet been set, so its value is still the default `100`. That results in the `MyLine` instances being placed at y values of `0`, `33.33`, and `66.66`. A better way to position the lines is to bind `placeLines()` to the `size` of `MyRectangle`. You can do this by modifying your `TestApp`:

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        myRectangle = MyRectangle()
        myRectangle.bind(size=myRectangle.placeLines)
        # myRectangle.placeLines()
        return myRectangle
```

And the `placeLines()` method must be adjusted to allow calling by `bind` by allowing additional args:

```
def placeLines(self, *args):
    self.line0.y = 0
    self.line1.y = self.height * 1/3
    self.line2.y = self.height * 2/3
```